# time complexities (Big-O notation) of the following running times expressed as a function of the input size N

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

Give the time complexities (Big-O notation) of the
following running times expressed as a function of
the input size N

```
a) N^12 + 25N^10 + 8
b) N + 3logN + 12n√n
c) 12NlogN + 15N2logN
```

Comment: a. 12 raised to N + 25 (10 raised to N) +8

Comment: c. 12NlogN + 15 N square log N

Comment: In future, please show your own working / attempts when posting a question. And btw, `N^12` is *"N raised to the power of 12"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) `N^12` is the dominant term - `O(N^12)`

b) `N√N` is the dominant term - `O(N√N)`. For a proof of why `log n` is smaller than any power term, see [this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1663818/does-the-logarithm-function-grow-slower-than-any-polynomial)

c) `N^2 > N` so `N^2 log N` is the dominant term - `O(N^2 log N)`